# In Mac how to switch between the projects' window in AndroidStudio?

Tags: macos, android-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

My OS is Mac.

I have opened several projects in AndroidStudio, sometimes I wanted to switch between the projects to choose a project. Is there any keyboard shortcuts to do it just like "command/ctrl + tab" ?

Answer (score 44):

Use **Cmd + ` (Cmd + Backtick)**. It switches between all the projects that are open on Android Studio.

Comment: This is not working i am using MAC OS  Android studio version 3.5.3

Comment: @user2447043, have you checked my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59764951/5468463? :)

Answer (score 14):

Sometimes it doesn't work because of conflicts with other shortcuts.
Go to the menu "Android Studio" -> "Preferences", choose "Keymap".
And, use the search field for quick access.
For example, I made **Ctrl+Shift+`** shortcut, which is easy to use with one hand.

[image: 1]

Comment: When I type Cmd+`, it reads as Cmd+DeadGrave. But it works all the same.

Answer (score 13):

In Android studio command to switch between diffrent project windows  (i.e. windows those are not minimised) is as following :

1. **⌘`** -> (i.e command + backtick) -> for next project window
2. ⇧⌘`-> (i.e shift + command + backtick) for previous  project window

You can add your preferable shortcuts in **Android studio -> Preference -> Keymap**

Comment: the problem here is that the android studio dont know the ` key  as backstick but as a DEADGRAVE ...

Answer (score 6):

For **AS 3.5.3** and after, open *Window* menu and look for *Next Project Window* or *Previous Project Window* options. They have the shortcut combinations next to them.

Precisely:

**Next Project     <kbd>⌥</kbd> <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>`</kbd>**

**Previous Project <kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd> <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>`</kbd>**

Answer (score 5):

I'm not familiar with the Mac version of Android Studio, but the standard key combo for switching between windows within an app on the Mac is cmd-` (cmd-backtick) unless the app maps that to something else.

Answer (score 2):

On a MacBook Pro keyboard getting the backtick requires pressing Shift so stock shortcut doesn't work (Studio 3).

But you can remap it to use the 'tick' instead :  ´
So it becomes ⌘ + ´ for next project
and ⌘ + shift + ´ for previous project (equivalent of ⌘ + `)

That is probably what the designer had in mind.
A forward tilted tick to indicate a forward navigation and the
backtick symbolizing "backwards".

See Android Studio -> Preferences -> Keymap -> Main Menu -> Window

Answer (score 1):

⌘` is the default shortcut. But since I have Android Studio 3 installed it doesn't work anymore. I solved this by replacing it through ⌘^ which is the same key combination.

Answer (score 1):

**Windows** - **Command** + **`** (Backtick)

**Mac**     - **Option** + **Command** + **`** (Backtick)

Answer (score 1):

**Command** <kbd>⌘</kbd> + **Backtick** <kbd>`</kbd>

It's Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
[image]

When I update android studio to version 4.2.1, I also can't switch project. When I swith to official keymap like "Eclipse (macOS)", I search "cmd+ Backtick". I find the name is "Active Next Window". So I switch to my keymap and search "Active Next Window" as the second screenshot. Then I set it to "cmd+ Backtick".
Backtick is the "'" key on keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

To switch between projects:
command+option+`