# Android Studio Keyboard shortcut for switching project Mac OS using android studio 3.5.3

Tags: macos, android-studio, keyboard-shortcuts, android-studio-3.0

Hi i am using `mac OS` anyone has any idea  `keyboard shortcuts` how to `switch projects` I am using `Android 3.5.3` I am using `Cmd +` (Cmd + Backtick)` it seems not working

Comment: Check my comment there in that post .. It doesn't work  with studio 3.5.3 please reopen the question i have edited the question

Comment: Are you sure the solution is provided works with Android Studio 3.5.3 ?

Comment: Please don't post duplicate questions

Comment: The existing answers don't satisfying you is not a reason to post duplicates. They will be always closed. Specially self-duplicates! On the other hand, have you tryied cmd+alt+backtick?

Comment: I invite you to look at my answer that I just posted on the original question https://stackoverflow.com/a/59764951/5468463

Comment: Love   this is working

Answer (score 0):

Cmd Option + (Cmd + Option+ Backtick)` is working for me.